# Probability of a sample mean

Tags: sampling

I am working on the following problem:

The Department of Environmental Protection demands that your power plant show a mean NOx emission less than 5lb/MWh. Your plant's daily NOx emission fluctuates randomly with a mean of 4.9lb/MWh and a standard deviation of 0.5lb/MWh.

If the DEP randomly selects and tests emissions on 30 independent days, what is the probability that the sample mean will exceed the limit? (Hint: sampling distribution, use cdf functions to calculate the probability (normalcdf()).

I am not sure how to start this -- I thought I would just plug the information into normalcdf() in my calculator, but I think this doesn't take the 30 sample size into account. Any advice?

Comment: The EPA will be adding 30 independent normal variables and then dividing by 30. What distribution does that produce?

Comment: Sample mean distribution?

Comment: Sure, that's what the hint says. What do you know about the properties of sample mean distributions?